# How to set jQuery draggable min/max-left and min/max-right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I made a copy of JSbin for practice, JSbin [link here](https://jsbin.com/gififikisa/edit?html,css,js,output), actual site [link here](http://79.170.40.181/emory.com/Project04/index.html).

This is just a practice for making the front-end of websites as I just started learning web dev little over a week ago. You can put in html, css and javascript in the editboxes, and a page spit out in Output just like the actual JSbin.

But the problem is that you can resize the divs pass other divs.

My idea to prevent this from happening is:
1. get the editboxes' current positions 
2. store the left/right position of the editbox if resized to 10% window width
3. set the min/max left and right for the draggable div

And hence the question. How do I set the max-left/right for the draggable.

Also, any idea on why the draggable before Output div is diificult to drag to the right.

Edit: How the site is structured. When you drag the .drag (.resize in my JSbin code), it changes its left and right div's left and right. And the draggables are contained in the #main's div.

```html
<div id="main>
  <div id="HTML"></div>
                
  <div class="drag"></div> //drag this left and right to change the right of the HTML and left of CSS
                     
  <div id="CSS"></div>
               
  <div class="drag"></div> //drag this left and right to change the right of the Css and left of JavaScript
                     
  <div id="JavaScript"></div>
                      
  <div class="drag"></div> //drag this left and right to change the right of the JavaScript and left of Output
                     
  <div id="Output"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you tried my answer ?

Comment: if you are using JQuery UI why dont you use the [resizable element with a min/max width](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#max-min) to prevent elements from overlapping?

Comment: It's not exactly a resize element. It's basically a draggable div which the editboxes look at to adjust their left and right accordingly. I tried to use resizable on just the editboxes, but I had some problems with resizing 2 boxes at the same time. Also, I'm really just trying to replicate JSbin, and using their ways. And they are using a draggable between the editboxes, but I just can't figure out how to set the min/max left/right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By taking advantage of jQuery Ui's built in draggable event which gives us position information and also allows us to set position on drag.

I came up with the following solution:

```
var dragDistance = 100;

$(".resize").draggable({
  axis: "x", 
  containment: "parent",
  drag: function( event, ui){ 

    ui.position.left = Math.min( ui.position.left,  ui.helper.next().offset().left + ui.helper.next().width()-dragDistance); 
    ui.position.left = Math.max(ui.position.left, ui.helper.prev().offset().left + dragDistance);

   resize();

  }
});
```

I removed your onDrag function in the process so it wouldn't interfere.

See the bin here:

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/sasitexoro/1/edit?js,output)

NOTES:

1. I haven't looked into it and maybe its just a JSBin issue because I can't reproduce it in your live site.  But if the boundary lines disappear while you are dragging the code won't work.  You'll probably have to increase the drag distance to the point where the lines don't disappear while dragging.
2. You may notice you have difficulty dragging the Output box that seems to be caused by the Iframe you have inside.  If I comment out the IFrame I can drag it just fine.  I haven't looked for a solution but perhaps experiment with some padding or margins so that the Iframe is not pegged so closely against the border.  Or maybe if you detached it from the DOM while dragging that would fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was thinking recoding, but I just got into web dev and it is a little hard to wrap my head around everything.

Comment: @J13t0u You bet, please mark this answer as accepted if it resolved your question or leave feedback. Thanks

Comment: almost perfect except if you move the item to the far right or bottom of the window and then resize the item is lost

Answer (score 2):

Use [**containment**](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment)

> Constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified element or
>   region.
>
> *For Eg:*

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
  containment: "parent"
});
```

> [**Click Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5a2BZ/196/) For a Demo

Comment: The draggables are contained in the main div. And check out how my site is structured. I don't know how containment would help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually keep track of the position of each of the windows in the `dragging()` function, and only call the `resize()` method if they don't overlap:

```
function dragging(event) {
  var CSS_left = parseInt($("#CSS").css("left"));
  var JavaScript_left = parseInt($("#JavaScript").css("left"));
  var Output_left = parseInt($("#Output").css("left"));
  var offset = 100;
  var checkOverlap1 = $(event.target).is("#1") 
                     && event.clientX + offset <= JavaScript_left 
                     && event.clientX >= offset;
  var checkOverlap2 = $(event.target).is("#2") 
                     && event.clientX + offset <= Output_left 
                     && event.clientX - offset >= CSS_left;
  var checkOverlap3 = $(event.target).is("#3") 
                     && event.clientX - offset >= JavaScript_left 
                     && event.clientX <= codeboxWidth - offset;

  if (checkOverlap1 || checkOverlap2 || checkOverlap3) {
    resize(event);
  }
}
```

Here's the complete example - I also refactored/simplified your "resize" function.

```js
var codeboxWidth = $("#codebox").width();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#codebox").height($(window).height() - $("#topbar").height());
  $(".content").height($("#codebox").height());
  $(".editbox").height($(".content").height() - $(".contentheader").height());
  $("#HTML").css("left", 0);
  $("#HTML").css("right", "75%");
  $("#CSS").css("left", "25%");
  $("#CSS").css("right", "50%");
  $("#JavaScript").css("left", "50%");
  $("#JavaScript").css("right", "25%");
  $("#Output").css("left", "75%");
  $("#Output").css("right", 0);
});

function resize(event) {
  if ($(event.target).is("#1")) {
    $("#CSS").css("left", event.clientX);
    $("#HTML").css("right", codeboxWidth - event.clientX);
  }
  if ($(event.target).is("#2")) {
    $("#JavaScript").css("left", event.clientX);
    $("#CSS").css("right", codeboxWidth - event.clientX);

  }
  if ($(event.target).is("#3")) {
    $("#Output").css("left", event.clientX);
    $("#JavaScript").css("right", codeboxWidth - event.clientX);
  }
}

$(".resize").draggable({
  axis: "x"
});

function dragging(event) {
  var CSS_left = parseInt($("#CSS").css("left"));
  var JavaScript_left = parseInt($("#JavaScript").css("left"));
  var Output_left = parseInt($("#Output").css("left"));
  var offset = 100;
  var checkOverlap1 = $(event.target).is("#1") 
                      && event.clientX + offset <= JavaScript_left 
                      && event.clientX >= offset;
  var checkOverlap2 = $(event.target).is("#2") 
                      && event.clientX + offset <= Output_left 
                      && event.clientX - offset >= CSS_left;
  var checkOverlap3 = $(event.target).is("#3") 
                      && event.clientX - offset >= JavaScript_left 
                      && event.clientX <= codeboxWidth - offset;

  if (checkOverlap1 || checkOverlap2 || checkOverlap3) {
    resize(event);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  font-family: Arial;
}
#topbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background: #EEEEEE;
  position: relative;
}
h2 {
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
#control {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 8px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
.option {
  margin: 0 -5px 0 0;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: black;
}
.option:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
.option:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.option:hover {
  background: #dee5e5;
}
.opactive {
  background: #EBF3FF;
}
.opinactive {
  background: 0;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
.inactive {
  display: none;
}
#codebox {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 width: 100%;
  position: static;
  top: 35px;
  background: white;
}
.content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 10%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  color: #6DCAFC;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.resize {
  top: 35px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  right: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: rgba(218, 218, 218, 0.498039);
  z-index: 99999;
  background: #666;
}
.contentheader {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
}
.selectedcontent {
  background: white;
}
.contentbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid darkgrey;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.editbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.textareabox {
  background: transparent;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Project 04</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="topbar">
    <h2>Code Runner</h2>
    <div id="control">
      <a href="#" class="option opactive">HTML</a>
      <a href="#" class="option opactive">CSS</a>
      <a href="#" class="option opactive">JavaScript</a>
      <a href="#" class="option opactive">Output</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="codebox">
    <div id="HTML" class="content active">
      <div class="contentbox">
        <div class="contentheader">HTML</div>
        <div class="editbox" id="HTMLeditbox">
          <textarea id="HTMLcode" class="textareabox"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="resize active" id="1" style="left: 25%" ondrag="dragging(event)"></div>

    <div id="CSS" class="content active">
      <div class="contentbox">
        <div class="contentheader">CSS</div>
        <div class="editbox" id="CSSeditbox">
          <textarea id="CSScode" class="textareabox"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="resize active" id="2" style="left: 50%" ondrag="dragging(event)"></div>

    <div id="JavaScript" class="content active">
      <div class="contentbox">
        <div class="contentheader">JavaScript</div>
        <div class="editbox" id="JavaScripteditbox">
          <textarea id="JavaScriptcode" class="textareabox"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="resize active" id="3" style="left: 75%" ondrag="dragging(event)"></div>

    <div id="Output" class="content active">
      <div class="contentbox">
        <div class="contentheader">Output</div>
        <div class="editbox" id="Outputbox">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="jscript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Here's a JSBin based on your example.](https://jsbin.com/denapekoyi/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: It doesn't resize the editboxes anymore, but it can still be dragged around, right?

Comment: What's "it"? This example shows how to keep track of whether your elements overlap. Your editboxes are still resized with their parent `<div>`s.