# How to stop jQuery draggable from dragging it off the screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I currently study Bootstrap and RWD in general and I want to build a responsive photo gallery to gain experience in these topics.

I have already built 95% of what I wanted to, except 1 thing.

Basically, I have a group of small images next to each other and when I click on the small image I can see it bigger.
This group of images is a jQuery draggable and the problem with that is I can drag it off screen if I want to.

```
$("#myDraggable").draggable({
    scroll: true,
    axis: "x",
    cursor: "move"          
});
```

What I see in answers of other similar questions is that people suggest to use `scroll: false` but that's not what I need since I want to be able to scroll.

I have all the code available on codepen: https://codepen.io/tomsoos/full/WRqeJR/

If you are not familiar with codepen you can click on the Change View button to change between the Editor View and the Full Page.

When you open the code in Full Page and try to drag the group of images off screen you will be able to do that.

My question is how can I prevent that but still be able to drag these images?

Answer (score 0):

use the containment option this will stop the item being dragged out of a container on the page.
Where the string passed is a jquery selector. have a look [Here](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) at the docs

for example.

```
  $("#myDraggable").draggable({
    scroll: true,
    axis: "x",
    cursor: "move",
    containment: "body"
 });
```

Comment: Thank you **Andrew** for taking the time to answer my question! I think I have already tried the `containment` option but it looks like it just stops my draggable from being dragged. I made the suggested changes to my code, [have a look at it](http://codepen.io/tomsoos/full/WRqeJR/). Again you can switch between Editor View and Full Page by clicking on the Change View button.

Comment: so you want the images to go off the screen but you. Want it to stop when the other end reaches the edge of the screen?

Comment: Yes, something like that. What I want is basically when the left side of my draggable is touching the left side of the screen, I don't want to allow it to be dragged to the right, only to the left. Similarly, when the right side of my draggable is touching the right side of the screen, I don't want to allow it to be dragged to left, only to the right, if that makes sense.

Comment: What you could try is on the drag event set the left value of the draggable to be the minimum of 0 and its current position and do a similar thing with right. Something like in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35231863/2398500)

Comment: Thank you **Andrew**! It looks promising but honestly I already moved on to another project, because I felt like I was just wasting my time. I might come back one day and try it again though.